# How to edit Synaptics Touchpad values in Ubuntu 12.04? No xorg.conf file!

Tags: xorg, synaptics

After I installed Ubuntu 12.04 got some issues with my touchpad.
I reported the problem and finally today a guy replied here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/992330
It seems that the solution was good because I edited HorizHysteresis and VertHysteresis using synclient:
`synclient VertHysteresis=48` and `synclient HorizHysteresis=48`
To see if they were really edited I run into terminal
`synclient` and just seen there the values I added. Everything is running perfectly till now. But after I restarted Ubuntu the values are gone and rolled back to default.
A guy told me to edit the xorg.conf file but there is no xorg.conf file in etc/X11.

Thanks and hope someone can give me a good solution.

Comment: Make one according to the format shown here:  http://askubuntu.com/a/126539/43660  You can create the file by typing `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` in the terminal.

Comment: Made it, now I need to add only the options I want? I mean, my file should look like this `Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option         "HorizHysteresis" "48"
    Option         "VertHysteresis" "48"
EndSection`

Comment: Edited with this options and values `Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "touchpad catchall"
    Driver             "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad    "on"
    Option         "HorizHysteresis" "72" 
    Option         "VertHysteresis" "72"
EndSection` and is working perfectly. Restarted and the configuration is there.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and the touchpad started working; the touchpad-tab was also visible in settings (mouse).