# How to change mouse speed/sensitivity?

Tags: mouse

I am on an Asus Zenbook UX32VD in Ubuntu 12.10. Both in 12.04 and 12.10 I haven't been able to change the mouse speed (i.e. the "sensitivity" in the mouse/touchpad dialog). I can change the slider, but nothing changes.

This is a big problem for me, since the mouse speed is somewhat slow. Any suggestions?

The problem is both for the touchpad and mouse.

Comment: I dont have this laptop - so hence this comment.  Maybe this Q&A can help - http://askubuntu.com/questions/130217/how-to-edit-synaptics-touchpad-values-in-ubuntu-12-04-no-xorg-conf-file .  If you type `synclient` you have some parameters such as `MinSpeed`, `MaxSpeed` & `AccelFactor` that you can play with.  Good luck.

Comment: I have installed LXInput from Softwarecenter. It's for LXDE but works also unter Unity. Anja

Answer (score 137, accepted):

First we need to identify the input `device ID` to change the speed/sensitivity. Open a terminal and run this command:

```
xinput --list --short
```

output:

```
abcd@abcd-abcde:~$ xinput --list --short

Virtual core pointer

↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳ Logitech USB RECEIVER                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

My pointing devices are a `Logitech USB RECEIVER` and a `Synaptics TouchPad`.
To list out device properties:

```
xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

**EDIT:**

Another option:
`xinput --list-props 11` as `11` is the number that is shown above in its parent property (SynPS/2 Synaptic TouchPad).

Now reduce it's property values to suit your need:

```
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   2.500000
```

using this command:

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```

**EDIT:**

Another option:
    `xinput --set-prop 11 267 1.5` where `11` is the device, just like from above, `267` is the id of the device property (Device Accel Constant Decleration) as you can see when device `11` is being listed all of properties being attached, and finally `1.5` is your desired speed.

You may have to play around with this number a bit to set it exactly as you need.

If you need to set this value automatically every time Ubuntu starts then:

create a .sh file

```
#!/bin/sh

xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```

change the file to executable :

```
chmod +x
```

and Put this in the start-up applications list.

Source : [Configuring Mouse Speed manually](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/)

Comment: I now have the same problem for my wireless logitech mouse with unified reciever. I can change the speed in the same way, but max speed (1) is way too slow! Any suggestions?

Comment: Try increasing the acceleration property. <"Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 5> . I also have a Logitech wireless mouse and i can't see any direct speed property. all i got is acceleration and deceleration. Please tell what speed property your device is showing and also try to increase the value of speed beyond 1 and see if that works..

Comment: I made the value 0.5 on ThinkPad e530c with Debian 8 and it's working sweetly :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me somehow. The .sh-file is being executed. Command works manually in console after start. Looks like the mouse is being detected after the .sh-file has been executed.

Comment: In that case you might have to trigger the script after the device is detected. Not sure how to do that. There must be some listener option though.

Comment: Linux mint 18, Logitech 510, xinput says "property 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format"

Comment: is there anyway to increase mouse speed w/o using acceleration?

Comment: @chovy you can try hacking with Coordinate Transformation Matrix, prop 144, (something like `xinput set-prop ?? 144 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1`) but you will loose precision

Comment: This option does not suit gamers. (Admittedly, I game on Windows, but I just dislike mouse acceleration.)

Comment: This worked for me. It's a bit verbose but in this case I like that it is verbose - makes it easier for me to understand what is going on. The biggest problem I have is picking useful values here.

Comment: Still works in 20.04.3.  Thanks!  +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) - `xinput --list --short | grep pointer`  can be used for more tidy appearance, and gave me twice the desired result, both (*`Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]`* - whichi is the header)
`⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Vertical Advanced Ergonomic Mouse Consumer Control id=25 [slave  pointer  (2)]` and `⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Vertical Advanced Ergonomic Mouse id=26 [slave  pointer  (2)]`. The second one with ID 26 was correct, the other one ending on `... Consumer Control` was void.

Answer (score 34):

Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, Logitech cordless TrackMan

xinput did nothing for me.

```
xset q
```

to check settings

```
xset mouse 3 0
```

This sets the acceleration to 3 and the threshold to zero. Not great settings but better than before.

If you want to use fractional value, you can enter fraction (i.e. 3/2) instead of floating point number.

The man page says the settings will be lost on logout/reboot.

Comment: If you want to use fractional value, you can enter fraction (i.e. 3/2) instead of floating point number. It's weird, but it works.

Comment: hmm, so what is the fastest speed that xset can do?

Comment: Thank you I was getting quite annoyed at my inability to manipulate bodhi linux mouse speed

Answer (score 28):

The above mentioned "Device Accel ..." options do not exist on my machine. Lenovo T440s running Ubuntu 18.04

Instead, I have success using these:

```
xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.5 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 1
```

The original "Coordinate Transformation Matrix was 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 and I have now half the speed, which is slow enough for me.

With this syntax, we can adjust horizontal and vertical speed separately.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have successfully used this to speed up my Logitech K520 mouse, so I wanted to mention that it appears to work for Logitech mice too. Oddly, the right-most number seems to slow down vertical scrolling at higher numbers, and speed up at lower ones.

Comment: This approach worked well with a Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse, where the mouse was too sensitive to use while walking on a treadmill.

Comment: My Microsoft Classic Intellimouse pointer was too slow on Ubuntu 20.04. The Acceleration and Sensitivity settings in the Mouse and Touchpad GUI were maxed out. xset did not have any effect. libinput Accel Speed was at it's maximum value of 1. I fixed it with `xinput --set-prop 12 149 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1`, where 149 is Coordinate Transformation Matrix.

Comment: Yes, this worked also for me with a speedlink mouse, shown as ARESON Wireless Mouse. A nice post about the matrices is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177640/55508

Answer (score 7):

You can use these scripts to set the touchpad and mouse speed each systemstart:

```
#!/bin/sh
TP=$(xinput --list --short|grep -i touchpad|cut -f 1 | cut -d" " -f 5-|sed 's/\s\+$//g')
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 10
```

For me, I think 1.5 and 10 are suitable values for the **touchpad**.

---

I use a Logitech usb mouse too.
So for a **Logitech** mouse use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
MOUSE=$(xinput --list --short|grep -i Logitech| cut -f 1|cut -d" " -f 5-|sed 's/\s\+$//g')
xinput --set-prop "$MOUSE" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.2
xinput --set-prop "$MOUSE" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 10
```

For me, I think 1.2 and 10 are suitable values for the **mouse**.

I created a project on Github:
https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed

Answer (score 4):

Running `sudo xset m 1 1` worked for me. 
My mouse speed now behaves in a normal behaviour like in Windows platform.

Answer (score 3):

I've fine-tuned deceleration by closing my eyes, before moving pointer to a certain place on the screen. After 5 adjustments, now my mouse moves that much as I'm expecting.

That's the line I'm using right now:

`xinput --set-prop "Bluetooth Mouse M557" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2.3`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others acceleration is not the same as speed. Until recently I used the `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` setting to scale the mouse velocity and disabled mouse acceleration with `xinput`. But this comes with its own issues - I had issues in Blender when doing mouse middle button drags to rotate the scene - The cursor was jumping as soon as I released the button. There is an [open issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/633).

But I found a way to directly set the DPI of the mouse. It is possible to create a setting file here:

```
sudo vim /etc/udev/hwdb.d/50-mouse-dpi.hwdb
```

With the following content - Replace `<name-of-the-device>` with the name shown in `xinput` (e.g. "Logitech G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse").

```
mouse:*:name:<name-of-the-device>:
 MOUSE_DPI=320
```

To apply the settings execute

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update && sudo udevadm trigger
```

Repeat until you find a DPI value which makes you happy.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work with a Logitech mouse

Comment: Tested with a Logitech MX Vertical and Ubuntu 20.04, it does not work.

Comment: This *did* work for me with a Logitech Ergo M575 trackball and Ubuntu 22.04.  Thanks!
Adding HWDB entries for mice is documented in the comments in `/lib/udev/hdwb.d/70-mouse.hwdb`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the 'simple' profile to increase the mouse resolution without acceleration.

```
#!/bin/bash

device="Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse"
resolution_percent="241" # Greater than 100, use constant deceleration otherwise with profile -1. 

xinput set-prop "$device" "Device Accel Profile" 4 # Simple profile with threshold 0 allows constant scaling up
xinput set-ptr-feedback "$device" 0 "$resolution_percent" 100 # Set threshold to 0 and acceleration to $resolution_percent/100
```

You'll have to modify the script by using your particular device name. You can look that up by running xinput without arguments. Also the script has to be run each time the mouse is connected or when you start the system.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to the previous answers that it's possible that there won't be `"Device Accel Constant Deceleration"` property. For example, I don't have it for Logitech G600 in Kubuntu 17.04. But there is
`"Coordinate Transformation Matrix"` which is even more power

Answer (score 1):

My Logitech MX518 mouse was too slow on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to set Accel speed prop to max (1), but it did not speed it enough.

After some more searching, found lomoco (Logitech Mouse Control) and installed it with

```
sudo apt install lomoco
```

The man page is here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/lomoco.1.html

The manual is good, but for a restless soul, this is what I did:

```
lomoco --scan
```

Got this as one of the output lines. c051 is the product ID.

```
002.004: 046d:c051 MX518 Optical Mouse (M-BS81A) Caps: RES
```

Then set the sensitivity

```
sudo lomoco -p c051 --1600
```

And got a fast mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Using a live environment of `19.10`, the following will set the max mouse speed.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse speed 1.0
```

To show all settings:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse speed 0.5
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 16.04 on my Mac and xinput worked fine with Magic Mouse. The only thing I needed to do was run it as root:

```
sudo xinput --set-prop 14 271 3.0
```

(I'm impressed how speedy was this mouse)

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary. this is a per-session setting

Answer (score 0):

I am running ubuntu 21.04 and changing the mouse speed is eeeeeazyyyy. This is not 12.10, but this is how you do it on 21.04 it will probably work on 12.10 if 12.10 is the same way. Here's how.

Click on the applications icon in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Search for `Settings`.

Click on `Settings` and go to `Mouse & Touchpad`.

There, it will have a `Mouse Speed` slider; slide it up like so.

[image]

That should do the trick if your gui is the same or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only allows adjusting mouse acceleration even though the label claims to adjust mouse speed.