# Change mouse speed and not the acceleration

Tags: mouse, xinput, gnome-control-center

I've been searching for a good few hours on how to change the mouse speed on Ubuntu 14.04, but all the answers and tutorials I find only teach me how to adjust the acceleration and not the speed. I need to lower my mouse speed. I like a bit of acceleration, but my mouse base speed is too high which means it's hard to aim for small buttons. How do I adjust just the mouse speed, with either `xset` or `xinput`, or other tools? Command line solutions are preferable, because I suspect the GUI for mouse and touchpad settings in Ubuntu 14.04 is bugged. There isn't much available to tweak besides the double click speed and laterality (right or left-handed, see attached image).

[image]

Comment: Read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity

Comment: interesting - this is probably a bug and you should report this.  Your screen is missing the pointer speed option that I'm seeing in 14.04 - http://i.imgur.com/95ZT7Ao.png

Comment: @Cornelius, I have read that before, and it only changes acceleration.

Comment: @fossfreedom, thanks for the vindication, I'll report the bug if I have time. Tweaking Linux and getting it to work as smoothly as Windows 7 is such a pain and a waste of time, I think I may switch back to Windows 7 instead. I'll play with Linux when I have more time, maybe after retirement. I really admire you hardline Linux boys. Where do you find the time?