# Increasing mouse speed

Tags: mouse

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have Ubuntu on my Laptop, as well as here, my Desktop. The laptop has the ability to change the speed of the mouse cursor, while the desktop does not. Both are running the same version of Ubuntu. The only difference being the laptop has only the Mouse running from the USB and the Desktop having a Mouse and Keyboard.

I've tried this in the Terminal, so far, without any noticeable change when changing the final number.

```
xinput --set-prop- 4 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1
```

I got the number ID number from, `xinput --list --short`.

Like it said in this question/answer:

[How to change mouse speed/sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity)

Thanks for any response, if you need further information, please ask. I wasn't to sure what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had another read through the topic I actually linked, in the question. Long story short, I must have input something wrong the first time around.

This worked for me :

xset
xset mouse 2 0

A reply by John Gomez. Thanks to everyone who took an interest :-).

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad, and you should find an option for mouse speed.

Comment: I mentioned above, I don't have the option. I only have the ability to alter my double click speed. As well as change from left to red button.