# decreasing scroll speed

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

I've recently switched to Ubuntu, and the one thing that has been bothering me is the scroll speed, which I can't seem to change. How can i decrease  scroll mouse speed on ubuntu 14.04 ? help me please

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad

There should be settings for pointer speed for both touchpad and mouse.

Comment: All of those settings are at ,,Slow" :( what can i do?

Comment: Theres a good answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity