# for my laptop DEll G15 5510 , in Ubuntu two-finger touch scrolling speed of touchpad is very high

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

for my laptop DEll G15 5510 , in Ubuntu two-finger touch scrolling speed of touchpad is very high , can anyone suggest soultion to slow it down. I tried few mentioned solutions like changing libinput measure but it failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [decreasing scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591155/decreasing-scroll-speed)