# How to lower pointer speed

Tags: mouse, 16.04

I have ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome and my mouse pointer speed is a little too fast. I already lowered it to the minimum in settings but it's still too fast/sensitive.
How can I make it even slower ?

PS: I am Linux noob so be specific in your answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, you can slow down the pointer speed by copy and pasting this into a terminal

```
xset m 3/2 5
```

#### How it works

from `man xset`

```
   mouse   The  m option controls the mouse parameters; it may be abbreviated to 'm'. Of course, it applies to most pointing devices, not just
           mice. The parameters for the pointing device are `acceleration' and `threshold'. The acceleration can be specified as  an  integer,
           or  as  a simple fraction. Threshold is just an integer. The setting is applied to all connected pointing devices. xinput(1) should
           be used if you need device-specific settings.
```

Comment: ok but it is permanet, will it remain after restart? and can you pls explain this comand

Comment: sorry, I don't know in my experience I tend to have the operating system fail before I get a chance to restart. I apply this at the time of installation and it works for me.