# I use a MOUSE not a joystick, please no more joystick answers! How do I change my pointer so I can see it better?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, configure

I am an old fart that has a tough time keeping an eye on my MOUSE pointer.  In Windows you can go to control panel, click on "mouse" and change the pointer style,  how fast my cursor goes across the screen, etc.  I found only a symbolic mouse app in Ubuntu that that does nothing that I can tell.  Logitech does not support Linux, so I don't know  where to go for these controls.  Is there anything out there?

Comment: Do you only want to change the pointer size, or do you need speed settings too?

Comment: Excellent question.  My father asked exactly the same when he migrated to Ubuntu.  I'm also interested in an answer.

Comment: @jawtheshark and OP ^ that will change the pointer size, but not the speed.

Comment: This will allow you to change your cursor speed http://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity

Comment: John, I don't care if you're an old fart or young guy - please format your questions and titles in professional manner.

Answer (score 1):

Install the **Unity Tweak Tool**, select the cursor tab, select **use large cursors** at the bottom of the window.

Unity Tweak Tool can probably be found in Synaptic, the Ubuntu Software Center, or at https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool.

Also, **Solaar** supports Logitech mice on Ubuntu. Find it at http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/