# "Upgraded" 16.04 to 17.04 Now unable to change mouse speed

Tags: mouse, 17.04

THE SLIDER DOES NOT WORK! THE FUNDAMENTAL SLIDER THAT'S SUPPOSED TO WORK... DOES NOT WORK!

```
xset m
```

Does NOT work

---

Mouse dump

```
mantis@toboggan:~$ xinput --list-props 10

Device 'Razer Razer Abyssus':
Device Enabled (143):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed (277): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (278): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (279):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (280):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (281):   1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (282):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (283):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (284): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (285): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (286):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (287):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (288):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (289): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (290): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (291):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (292):    0
Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event4"
Device Product ID (266):    5426, 66
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (293):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (294):   1
```

Yeah, no Constant Deceleration here!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mouse speed/sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity)

Comment: `libinput` is not supported by the GUI. You can set the speed using config files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and struggled for quite a while until finding the solution. Most other tutorials tell you to set the property "Device Accel Constant Deceleration".

However, my mouse and as it seems yours too uses **libinput**.

So the property is a bit different and is called "libinput Accel Speed" https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput

Try setting the speed with the following command:

**xinput --set-prop 10 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.8**

NB: The values are betwean -1 and 1

Comment: To make this setting persist after rebooting, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/461173/22414