# How to install package from Ubuntu install DVD?

Tags: mouse, 17.04

i recently installed Ubuntu 17.04. Iam new to Ubuntu, used Windows before. I tried to make my mouse act like it did in Windows. Unfortunately even the fastest setting of mousespeed was too slow for me, so i found this tip:
["Upgraded" 16.04 to 17.04 Now unable to change mouse speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905424/upgraded-16-04-to-17-04-now-unable-to-change-mouse-speed)
(all other solutions i could find did also not help)
it did not help in making the mouse speed faster, but after rebooting Ubuntu i am now left without mouse and keyboard. Both are disabled. Both are generic USB devices.
I suppose if i reinstall the package "xserver-xorg-input-libinput" iam fine.
However, i tried booting into recovery mode and installing the package which fails.
In recovery mode menu, when i select "network" to enable network to download and install the package, it fails with some messages:

> grep: /etc/resolv.conf: File or Folder not found
>
> Trying to start NetworkManager ...
>
> Unknown Group "power" in message bus configuration file
>
> grep: /etc/resolv.conf: File or Folder not found

Methods from [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Recovery-Modus/) i could find about how to enable internet in recovery console, also failed.
Now iam looking for a way to install the package from the ubuntu install DVD.
Looking forward to your advice.
Stefan

UPDATE:

Although this is not a solution to my question about how to add packages from install-dvd, i found a solution about how to enable networking in recovery mode: get into root consle, enter the following lines:

> mount -o remount,rw /
>
> dhclient enp3s0
>
> echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null

if you cant find out your ethernet interface's name(enp3s0 above), try iwconfig (ifconfig is not installed by default)
After these steps i was able to reinstall the package i deleted, using apt-get install. Mouse and Keyboard are working again :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the package on your DVD (or online), and then use:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```