# 17.04: mouse has become slow

Tags: mouse, 17.04

Since I upgraded to 17.04, my mouse has become a lot slower. I had set it to max fast, which I like, but now it feels like less than half as fast. I have to move my hand a lot further to reach the other end of the screen, while before, a short twist of my wrist would do the job.

How can I make my mouse pointer a lot faster, if in the settings menu it's already at maximum? I'm looking for increasing pointer acceleration in particular.

Please, Ubuntu developers, make increasing mouse speed and acceleration easy.

Comment: Look at the duplicate for "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"

Comment: Christine I see you added a note about acceleration. You can look [then at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity).

Comment: I was hoping the answer would be simpler than having to type "xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5" in a shell. Especially since my other laptop running Ubuntu and my desktop computer running Ubuntu are fine.

Comment: Well @Christine, you can report a bug to your DE. E.g. in systemsettings5 of KDE acceleration capped at pretty big value of "20.0", so I don't know why your DE have a smaller limit. Btw, you can also try `systemsettings5` for that matter — it may work anyway.