# Change mouse speed in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse

How can I increase my mouse speed beyond the speed settings possible in "Settings"? Even on the fastest setting, it is still too slow. I tried xinput, but get warning that I would be running against an XWayland server, therefore, xinput would not work. Besides, xinput --list --short command does not return anything that I could guess is my mouse.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and a wired mouse Logitech G502 Hero.

Thanks!

Comment: there are a number of option to try in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity)

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with a MS IntelliMouse, nothing works. lxinput, xinput, xset, lomoco, piper all either don't find my mouse or have no effect. I am stuck with the Settings app maximum which is clearly not enough... (Note that gsetting works but with the same maximum than the settings app)

Answer (score 1):

I found a utility called *Solar* which supports many *Logitech* devices not supported by the *Piper* utility and worked for my *Logitech m310*.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution myself - install "Piper", a mouse configuration utility, available at the Ubuntu software store. It can change the DPI resolution, which solves the issue.

Comment: `piper` doesn't find my mouse ... 22.04 using a Microsoft USB mouse.