# Keep synclient settings persistent

Tags: synaptics

I've created `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-userdefined.conf` file (copy of `50-synaptics.conf`, only desired stuff changed and posted) with the following contents:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "true"
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "106"
    Option "RTCornerButton" "0"
    Option "SHMConfig" "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

However, the settings aren't applied and every time Ubuntu starts I have to apply the settings manually. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar question with solution can be found [here]. It is a smarter approach because new system updates may override *50-synaptics.conf* [here]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130393/how-to-configure-the-touchpad-middle-click/156545#156545

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure the touchpad middle click?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130393/how-to-configure-the-touchpad-middle-click)

Comment: @ElectricGoat I did what you said, but it's not working. Could you have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/748729/making-custom-synaptics-touchpad-config-persistent-not-working ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I discovered a utility called synaptiks. (I'm using KDE now)

It solved the problems I had.

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) solution:

Hmm :-/ I'm afraid this didn't work for me with ubuntu 16.04 Dell XPS13. Instead I discovered, Touchegg

https://samtinkers.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/3-finger-gestures-in-ubuntu-16-04/

```
sudo apt install touchegg
```

To enable 3 finger and above touch in Ubuntu 16.04 (of course be sure your touchpad driver supports multitouch, or else upgrade your kernel)

Go to your home directory and create an `.xprofile` with the following content:

then

```
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0
touchegg &
```

Now after you reboot your laptop, you’ll be able to use gestures.

Comment: Finally a good -- and easy --  16.04 solution. I added this as a header to stress the momentary relevance.

Comment: Instead of installing touchegg and writing those commands in `.xprofile`, you can write those commands directly in `.bashrc`. It works for me on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

A comment in the file reads:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
```