# Touchpad hardware buttons not working

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, button

I'm a beginner in Ubuntu and I have version 14.04 LTS installed. I checked the previous answers and forums but so far I've not been able to make this working!

My issue is that the touchpad hardware buttons (left and right) do not work. Also scrolling is out-of-order. Single tapping works as left button and if I use the mouse everything works fine.

Touchpad is listed as input device, however `synclient` does not work (driver not loaded?) but the driver is installed.

Oh, I have a M301Z Dell laptop, which I understand works pretty well with Ubuntu...

Comment: Please check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453876/how-to-install-synaptiks-on-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04). This might help you to sort out.