# Trackpad not found Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

hello I have a problem with my trackpad ,that it cant be found by my Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed this guide [Install Synaptics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453876/how-to-install-synaptics-on-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04) but this error appears as I type `synaptiks`

```
No touchpad found
No touchpad was found in this system. If the system has a touchpad, please make sure that the synaptics driver is properly installed and configured.
If your touchpad is not found, though the driver is installed and configured correctly, please compile detailed information about your touchpad hardware and report this issue to the issue tracker.
```

Also this is my output on `xlist`

```
    ~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Upgrade kernel to 4.4 by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The most likeliest reason is it might not have located a driver for it. What you should do is on Google, search for a driver for your trackpad. For now, you can use a mouse.