# middle mouse button acer aspire vn7

Tags: mouse, touchpad, acer

My acer aspire v15 nitro comes with a touchpad.
Unfortunately there is no middle-mouse button.

Some internet forums talk about pushing the upper right corner for a middle mouse click but that does not seem to do anything on my touchpad neither.

Clicking left and right buttons simultaneously has no effect.

Does anyone have a workable setup for a middle mouse button on this laptop?

Comment: Have you seen this thread: http://askubuntu.com/q/130393 ? There are several possible solutions in it.

Comment: No. I will try them out and give an update on what works for me.

Comment: If the above doesn't help, can you [edit] your question and provide the output to `synclient`?

Answer (score 1):

If pushing both left and right mouse buttons simultaneously doesn't work I would consider setting up some other 'shortcut' for middle-mouse button. Three-fingers tap seems reasonable for me. You should be able to enable it using the following command in terminal.

```
synclient TapButton3=2
```

`TapButton3` means '3 fingers tap' and `2` is the number associated with middle mouse button.
It should work instantly. If so, I would suggest adding this command to 'Startup applications' as it may stop working after reboot. I didn't find any better solution to avoid it.

In general `synclient` takes care of your touchpad and let you configure it. Just try `synclient -l` to get list of available actions. Feel free to configure it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found a way that works for the missing 3rd mouse button issue:

https://askubuntu.com/a/902976/354678

Give the guy a credit if it works for you, too.