# How to enable middle button click at startup?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, standby

I'm trying to enable the middle click with 3 fingers on my touchpad using`synclient ClickFinger3=2`. I know from similar questions that the modification is not permanent after standby, so I used the workaround provided in the first answer of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130393/how-to-configure-the-touchpad-middle-click/288787) question in order to avoid this problem.
But the problem is that when I turn on the computer, the middle button click does not work and only when resuming from standby it starts to work perfectly.
I check the output of synclient right after the startup and the setting `ClickFinger3=2` is already there. So the option is already set but it starts to work after a resume from standby.

Comment: Try removing the spaces in `ClickFinger3 = 2`, this is just my guess on a possible solution, but there could be no difference.

Comment: When you say 'startup' do you mean Ubuntu 'Startup Applications'?

Comment: @Owen Hines thank you but the spaces were just in the output of synclient shown in terminal, not in my command

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: No, I'm sorry I mean just right after the start up, until you resume after a standby. I'll edit the question

Comment: Probably the setting was applied, but effectively broken or overruled because it was set too early. Run on startup the same command as in your current solution, but with a delay of say 15 seconds: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && <command_to_set_the_mouse>"`

Comment: Agreed with Jacob but would start more modest with 2 second sleep.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried with sleep 2, 15 and more but still have the same problem. I've notice that even by manually typing `synclient ClickFinger3=2` in the terminal after power on, the middle click doesn't work. Maybe it needs a sequence of commands like first disabling 2 fingers click, then adding 3 fingers click or something like that, what do you think? (As usual after resume everything works)

Comment: Hi @newman_ash to find out, could you startup your computer, open a terminal and run `dconf watch /` (keep it running). Subsequently go into standby and wake up again. Might very wll give us usefull information on what relevant setting is possibly edited.

Comment: @JacobVlijm thank you. This is the output of `dconf watch /`
  `$ dconf watch /  
/apps/update-manager/launch-time 1475918972  
/com/canonical/unity/minimize-count 38`  
But as you can see, nothing much happened, just the update manager showing out

Comment: @newman_ash Ah, that's a pitty, I was hoping for something relevant to be changed in dconf...