# Ubuntu 19.10 - touchpad and shutdown issues

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, shutdown, 19.10

First question here,

After installing Ubuntu 19.10 earlier today, I got some issues with the touch pad, that I partially managed to fix : cursor was freezing and middle click didn't work anymore. The cursor issue seems to be resolved for good but the middle click does't work anymore after the fixes I tried.
 
For the middle click issue this seems to be the solution [Link](https://askubuntu.com/a/156545/508262) and  [Link2](https://askubuntu.com/a/228313/508262) .
For the cursor freezing I had to edit Grub and it resolved the issue.

Furthermore, about one out of two times, shuting down the computor isn't working, it gets stuck on the Ubuntu loading screen.

My PC is : MSI P65-Creator-8RF, and the touch pad : ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad. Are those issues known and if yes do you have some solutions to propose.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : now the keyboard, sometimes, refuses to work and I cannot even connect to my account anymore. Otherwise I have to use the Screen Keyboard, which is impractical.

Edit 2 : sometimes it just crashes and Ubuntu is unusable.

Edit 3 : Resolving an issue recreates sometimes one that was resolved before.