# Disable middle click with Wayland

Tags: touchpad, wayland, synaptics, multi-touch

I switched my ubuntu from 21.10 impish to 22.04 jammy which implied to leave x11 for wayland.

I prevented unsolicited selection paste or unwanted closed tabs by completely disabling middle click with this line into my **.bashrc** :

`xinput set-prop 'Synaptics TM3289-021' 'libinput Middle Emulation Enabled' 1`

It was working fine with x11. After the upgrade, I get this error message

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
```

unable to find device Synaptics TM3289-021

When I do `xinput list`, I don't get my touchpad but rather

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**How can I disable middle click with Wayland protocol?**

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: For gnome: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution

Use the command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation true`

When we enable middle click emulation, if there is a real middle button on your touchpad he'll be disabled. You don't need to put it into your *.bashrc* to keep it persistant. Here is the [property description](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html#middle-button-emulation). You can customize it using **dconf-editor** gui (faster than command line)

If you don't know what [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) is.

### Why it wasn't working anymore

Wayland use libinput is instead of xinput. Therefore, you won't be able to change settings with xinput anymore.
[image: Libinput on wayland]
More informations on [libinput documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/what-is-libinput.html#what-libinput-is)

### Bonus: Exploring **/dev/input**

I found this very interesting [tutorial](https://thehackerdiary.wordpress.com/2017/04/21/exploring-devinput-1/) explaining how to explore input devices.

Here is some python3 code to discover mouse input:

```
import struct
f = open( "/dev/input/mouse0", "rb" );
while 1:
  data = f.read(3)                 # Reads the 3 bytes
  print(struct.unpack('3b',data))  # Unpacks the bytes to integers
```

Save it into a *file.py* and run `sudo python3 file.py`

Comment: Then you shouldn't have the problem and fixing it using: xinput set-prop 'your device' 'libinput Middle Emulation Enabled' 1.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Thinkpad L14, Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Solution DOES work on Ubuntu 22.04 on HP laptop. Annoying middle button is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this method from the Hyprland FAQ, and it works great!

```
wl-paste -p --watch wl-copy -p ''
```

It requires wl-clipboard to be installed.