# Middle Click Not Emulated in 22.04

Tags: mouse

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell Latitude. With 20.04, I was able to click the left and right buttons at the same time to simulate a middle click, but after my upgrade, it doesn't simulate middle click anymore. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: @Nmath It was just default functionality, if I remember correctly.

Comment: No, it was default functionality for me. It's possible it's the way my laptop was sending the buttons.

Comment: this might help. It's a question from somebody trying to disable this functionality. You could try just doing the opposite of what those answers suggest: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405449/disable-middle-click-with-wayland

Comment: Hey, that worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @craq, I followed the solution at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417258/410645) answer and it worked!

All I had to do was open a terminal and give it the command to enable middle mouse button emulation:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation true`

Comment: What kind of "upgrade" is this? Are they intentionally breaking functionality?

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this for a mouse instead of a touchpad

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation true
```