# How to disable three finger gestures on touchpad?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, multi-touch, macbook-pro, gestures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable the multitouch gestures in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu)

I am using 12.04 on a macbook pro. Everything works really well,except... I want to disable 3 finger gestures. It is way to easy to accidentally drag/move a window(3 finger gesture) while scrolling(2 finger gesture) when using a touchpad.

I found this answer on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu/133430#comment179860_133430). It was marked answered but it is not. The functionality is still there. All this recommendation does is disable the drag marks on the window.

This may be tricky because I want to disable 3 finger gestures but not 2 finger gestures. (ie I don't want to disable touchpad gestures all together)