# Disable touchpad switch application?

Tags: touchpad

When i'm scrolling sometimes ubuntu will think i'm trying to switch applications.

Is there a three finger application switching feature in ubuntu 13.04 that i don't know about?

It sometimes also switches applications when my palms are touching. I tried disable while typing and it's not optimal or user friendly. It's rather annoying to me.

Comment: Did you figure it out? For me it happens when I click and it detects two fingers..

Comment: No. But i found a wiki on it https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Comment: For what its worth, I'm experiencing this issue in 14.04 :( Just upgraded; very frustrated...

Comment: Possible answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This is three finger tap followed by hold to switch between app windows. The explanation here. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running following command solved the problem.

```
synclient ClickFinger3=2
```

Answer (score 0):

The Window List will switch applications if you scroll while the cursor is over it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

This was messing with my head, too. I couldn't figure out how to reproduce it until I read the Multitouch wiki posted by bagustris in his comment [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/452579/753970).

Running

> synclient ClickFinger3=2

immediately fixed the problem. Note that I ran

> synclient -l > ~/.config/synclient_listYYYYMMDD

first to preserve the original listings.

Comment: Could you please also add the link to the post you have read?

Comment: Done - apologies for omitting it.

Answer (score 0):

This one solves my problem:

`synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0`