# Two-finger scroll plus one-finger touch brings up annoying menu

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad, scrolling

This is driving me absolutely insane.

I recently upgraded to 14.04.2, and ever since, if I am scrolling using two fingers on the trackpad and I accidentally touch the trackpad with a third finger, a menu opens in the middle of the screen containing all my active apps.

The only way I can get it to go away is to wait about ten seconds and then click on one of the apps, switching over to it, and then switch back to whatever app I was originally on.

For some reason it's incredibly hard to do intentionally. When I can reproduce it, the menu goes away immediately and I am switched over to whatever app I was using before my current app. No matter what I do, I can't intentionally get the menu to stay on the screen. But when done accidentally, it never goes away immediately.

I don't even know what to search, other than variations of "ubuntu 14.04 two-finger scroll plus one-finger touch", which yields no results.

Does anyone know how I can disable this feature, or at least know what it is called, so I can research it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable the multitouch gestures in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are looking for: multi-touch gesture.

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch) you can see a list of these.

You can search for multi-touch gesture on askubuntu, others have similar problems, e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this feature is called coasting, and you can disable it by running:

```
synclient CoastingSpeed=0
```

(taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Mouse#Disable_coasting_.28scrolling_after_release.29)