# Disable three finger paste on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

How do I disable three finger paste in Ubuntu 16.04?
The output of `xinput list-props <Touchpad>`

looks like this:

```
Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (276): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (277): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (278):    0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (279):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (280):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (281):   0
libinput Accel Speed (282): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (283): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (284):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (285):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (260): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (261):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (262):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (286): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (287): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (291): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (292):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (293):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (294):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (295):    0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (296):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (297):    1
Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event17"
Device Product ID (264):    1739, 31251
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (298):   <no items>
libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (265):    1
```

Also, Can't run [synclient](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu/198524#198524):

Gives me this error:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Comment: please review this, https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu/198524#198524

Comment: @MD9 Already tried that. I get this error "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Answer (score 0):

turn off MiddleEmulation in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` file. 
sample below

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MiddleEmulation "off"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```