# Elan touchpad sluggish in Ubuntu 12.04I

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I checked the xorg.conf and it says "synaptics" as the device and driver name. The touchpad does feel like it's lagging when moving around but all the other features work (right/left click, multitouch etc). I want to fix the sluggishness, and make it smooth and responsive. I've tried the touchpad settings to no avail. Is there a fix for this (if any)?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is still an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I personalize my MacBook Pro Touchpad?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126526/how-can-i-personalize-my-macbook-pro-touchpad)

Answer (score 0):

Whats your HW ?

Mine:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
Aspire E5-571
```

For mine Bluetooth and Touchpad works with a new kernel.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/557370/355307