# help with synclient configuration on an Elantech touchpad

Tags: touchpad, asus, input-devices, synaptics

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my brand new ASUS K55V.

The touchpad behaves weird - two finger tap is interpreted as right-click, click and drag is not working (a double click is needed) and so on. Two finger scrolling (horizontal & vertical) works great.

I want the touch pad to behave the "normal" way (that is - like in my old laptop...). I read the [synclient documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Synclient) and many of the questions posted here, and I can even make some stuff work. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to make these work:

1. Click and drag (that is - physically clicking the button and dragging a finger)
2. Clicking in the right side of the button interpreted as right-click
3. Clicking button with two fingers interpreted as middle-click.

specs: The touchpad is equipped with a physical button that clicks. Here's the output of `xinput list-props "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" | grep Capabilities`:

```
 Synaptics Capabilities (294):  1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

1. Enable the `ClickPad` option in `synaptics` (terminal command: `$ synclient Clickpad=1`)
2. Mess with the `SoftButton` options. The [instructions here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/synaptics.4.html) describe the steps well.
3. Either by altering the `SoftButton` configuration as above, or by changing the `ClickFinger2` option, as suggested by @kmassada (or both)

Comment: why don't you edit my answer, include everything in there as a unified neat answer for people who may have this issue in future. Leave my suggestions but add more, maybe what I entered may help someone too.

Comment: @kmassada I think the best would be to leave the situation as it is - both answers are visible to people who'll search for this problem. Anyhow, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into `touchegg` and if it is supported by your hardware. (I think configuring mouse using this technique is easier but review my other answer first)

Also look at these options in this link 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man4/synaptics.4.html

its been a while I've done this, but if you set this option to 3, I think it will change the two finger click to middle. (3)

```
Option "TapButton2" "integer"
          Which  mouse  button is reported on a non-corner two-finger tap.
          Set to 0 to disable. Property: "Synaptics Tap Action"
```

This should take care of your right click I believe. (2)

```
Option "ClickFinger2" "integer"
              Which mouse button  is  reported  when  left-clicking  with  two
              fingers.   Set  to  0  to  disable.  Property:  "Synaptics Click
              Action"
```

the click and drag I believe has to do with palm detect and few other things. (1)

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad catchall"
MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Driver "synaptics"
Option "JumpyCursorThreshold" "200"
Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "20"
Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "5"
Option "TapButton2" "3"
Option "PalmDetect" "1"
Option "PalmMinWidth" "20"
Option "LockedDrags" "1"
Option "AccelFactor" ".01"
Option "MaxSpeed" "1.0"
Option "RBCornerButton" "3" 
EndSection
```

best of lucks

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out the solution was enabling the `ClickPad` option. I'll elaborate in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

TapButton is the key.

```
synclient | grep TapButton
```

TapButton1 means tap with 1 finger, TapButton2 means 2, and so on.

Set TapButton1=n, n could be:

- 1 = left click
- 2 = middle click
- 3 = right click

To sum up:

```
# 1 finger for left click, 2 for mid, 3 for right.
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=2 TapButton3=3
```

At last, add my [script](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/.dotfiles/blob/master/.enable-multi-touch-pad) to "Startup Applications".

Answer (score 0):

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=2 TapButton3=3
```

as mentioned above helps me a lot for

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
Aspire E5-571
```

Also using https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings/
to enable **VertTwoFingerScroll** and **HorizTwoFingerScroll**. It works.
Maybe synclient can enable it too, but the app works well.

But I installed a new kernel to get **Bluetooth working**.
Howto: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/11/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-18-rc3-in-linux.html

```
lsusb -v
:
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Radio Frequency
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04ca Lite-On Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x300b 
:
uname -srvm && cat /proc/cmdline 
Linux 3.18.0-031800rc3-generic #201411022335 SMP Sun Nov 2 23:36:52 UTC 2014 x86_64
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-031800rc3-generic root=UUID=53ff149f-97ba-47eb-b774-c44ba26a1fb9 ro noquiet nosplash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor vt.handoff=7
```

Have fun.