# Enable clickpad middle click on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, 12.10, mouse, touchpad

Currently running ubuntu 12.10 on my Acer Aspire S3 ultrabook and i've been fighting with it trying to get the mouse middle click to use three finger tap on it.

I could do this without an issue on 12.04 using this method - [How can I personalize my MacBook Pro Touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126526/macbook-pro-touchpad-optimization-12-04-lts/126539#126539) but this doesn't work on 12.10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone........?

Comment: I tried this: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse middle-button-enabled true` as seen [here](http://blog.karssen.org/2012/11/03/enabling-middle-mouse-button-emulation-in-ubuntu-12-10/) but it didn't work either. I have a Lenovo touchpad and you used to be able to emulate middle click by clicking with two fingers. It works on other distros, but not Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Surely there must be a fix out there somewhere -.-

Answer (score 2):

I am also looking for a good solution, right now I run the following command in terminal each time I start the computer and after suspend:

```
$ synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

I can't live without middle button on clickpad!

Comment: Seems like the preferred way to "middle click" in Ubuntu is to tap the upper right part of the touchpad. Tap the lower right part of the touchpad to right click.