# Sluggish/Unresponsive Mouse in 14.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

Just upgraded from 13 to 14.04 and the mouse on the touchpad is slow and/or unresponsive when dragging around the screen. No issue whatsoever in 13.

Comment: @Clayton this is not a macbook pro, how is this related?

Comment: @Braiam Well, teratogen just offered an answer using a [solution from that very question](http://askubuntu.com/a/343629/89515). Nothing in the question said that the system WASN'T a MacBook Pro and the OP gave no indication about what methods had already been tried.

Comment: Additionally, all of the fixes offered might very well be useful to the problem as described.  *But I get your message*, in the future I will add the link as a "Comment" to reference that article and see if any of the solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pointing Devices

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

It contains a nice GUI for changing touchpad settings like sensitivity, min/max speeds and palm detection.

Comment: thanks, I tried that tool however the issue seems to be intermittent lack of response. For example, I can swipe my finger across one instance and have it move, the next swipe there is no movement.